# NSCoding with Custom init

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, nscoding

I have a class named "Defense" with custom init method as below:

```
// initialize the defense unit and add the sprite in the given layer
- (id) initWithType:(DefenseType)tType andInLayer:(CCLayer *)layer {

    NSString       *fileName;
    fileName     = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:defenseStructuresFile[tType]];

    if ( (self = [super initWithFile:fileName]) ) {

        type              =   tType;
        maxHealth         =   defenseStructuresHealth[tType];
        health            =   maxHealth;
        mapRef            =   (SkirmishMap *)layer;        
    }
    return self;
}
```

now i am making my class `NSCoding` compatible, which requires the following 2 methods:

```
- (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder
- (void) encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder
```

When I normally allocate an instance of "Defense", I code as follows:

```
Defense                 *twr;
twr                 =   [[Defense alloc] initWithType:type andInLayer:mapRef];
```

and when I want to restore a saved instance of Defense object I code as

```
twr                 =   [[decoder decodeObjectForKey:kDefense] retain];
```

But in the above code I cant pass the "type" and "mapref" parameters, which are very much required to `initialize` the object...

The Defense class derives from `CCSprite` and since `CCSprite` doesn't conform to `NSCoding`, it is fine to call `(self = [super initWithFile:fileName])` from my `initWithCoder` method. But I require the `type` parameter to determine the filename to be passed to `ccsprite's` initWithFile.

So what would I do in this situation?
Should I change my class design? if yes, how?

Any good ideas/suggestions are highly appreciated... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder
{
    DefenseType earlyType;
    NSString *filename;

    earlyType = [decoder decodeIntegerForKey:@"defense"];

    if (earlyType == somethingIllegal) {
        [self release];
        return nil;
    }

    // Now do something with earlyType do determine filename

    self = [super initWithFilename:filename];
    if (!self) return nil;

    type = earlyType;
    // Decode the rest.

    return self;
}
```

When your methods are entered (even `init`'s) then `self` is always set. And it's just a variable (or to be more precise: an argument). This is why `[self release]; return nil;` will work even before calling `super`. When you call `self = [super initWithFoo:];` you're overwriting `self`. This is done because your super class might do `[self release]; return nil;` or allocate a concrete subclass and return that instead (when using a class cluster). So before you call super's initializer, it's not safe to overwrite instance variables, but it's OK to use normal stack variables (or even global variables).

Comment: thanks a lot ur answer :) i dont think i understood ur answer exactly. But i learned "self" is not some magic, but just another variable. and regarding my problem, u said like "defensetype" should be saved and restored, instead of passing from the owner object. and yeah that will work i suppose.. thx again :)

Comment: it worked by encoding and decoding the defensetype inside the defense class, in case `initWithCoder` is called. For normal allocation, i use my old `initWithType: andInLayer:`